# Answer checking script

Tags: javascript

I got this basic script which I'll be using to check if the answer is right. The only problem is that I'll be using with many forms. That's why I need this code to be more like DRY code.

```
            function checkAnswer()
        {
            var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
            if (answer.toLowerCase() == "correct answer")
            {
                alert("Well done!");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Too bad!");
            }

            var answer2 = document.getElementById("answer2").value;
                     if (answer2.toLowerCase() == "correct answer")
            {
                alert("Well done!");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Too bad!");
            }

            var answer3 = document.getElementById("answer3").value;
            if (answer3.toLowerCase() == "correct answer")
            {
                alert("Well done!");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Too bad!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: This looks hypothetical code, as if you had copy-pasted the first answer handling and added numbering 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Checking against a string like this is error prone. What happens if you accidently misspell "correct" one of the times? You're better off using a number constant as an enum to signify success/failure (After rereading your post, I realized I may have misinterpreted your intent).
2. I'd just extract that repeated bit into a function:

   ```
   function answerIsCorrect(answer, correctAnswer) {
       return answer.toLowerCase() === correctAnswer;
   }
   ```

   Then, since you're also repeating the use of this code, you might as well use a loop to prevent duplication:

   ```
   function checkAnswers(correctAnswers) {

       //You could also just use a standard for-loop for this
       correctAnswers.forEach(function(correctAnswer, i) {
           //Note unless you check prevent i from being appended when i == 1,
           // your first answer ID will be "answer1" instead of "answer"
           var answer = document.getElementById("answer" + (i + 1)).value;

           if (answerIsCorrect(answer, correctAnswer)) {
               alert("Well done!");

           } else {
               alert("Too bad!");
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   `correctAnswers` could also be a list of numbers, representing each answer's position in the list of answers. This would mean you would only need to check the **index** of the answer, instead of the **value** of the answer, which would make manipulations like `toLowerCase` unneccessary.
3. Your indentation is a little off at the top, but that could be a pasting error.